# Angular Form valid not workling

Tags: angular, forms

I want to use "formControl" to check if the form valided is or not.

but if in a form there is a input field with auto complete element, then the formcontrol is not workling

the code as follows:

```
 <form  [formGroup]="form">
<input matInput type="text" [formControl]="field"  [(ngModel)]="node.field" [name]="node.id"
               [matAutocomplete]="auto" placeholder="Field"/>
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let field of fields" [value]="field.value">
            {{field.value}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
</form>
```

```
public field: FormControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
```

```
 this.form.get('field').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      if (val === '') {
        status = true;
      }
    });
```

every time when I change the value of input field, the function valueChanges will be not called.

any solution?

Comment: Can you show the HTML for all ancestors of the input, and show all code where you are building the form in your component.ts

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code

Comment: Could you add the relevant code from component.ts as well

Comment: User, you needn't use [(ngModel)], (you are using reactiveForm, so remove it). And if your're using a formControl, you need use `this.field.valueChanges.susbcribe(...)` (you has not this.form)

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `[(ngModel)]` in combination with reactive form directives.

Once you're inside a `[formGroup]`, you can use `formControlName`, `formGroupName`, and `formArrayName` directives - you don't need to bind to instances of `FormControl`, `FormGroup`, and `FormArray`. The structure in the HTML should match the structure of the form you build in your component code.

```html
<form  [formGroup]="form">
  <input matInput type="text" formControlName="field"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto" placeholder="Field"/>
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let field of fields" [value]="field.value">
      {{field.value}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</form>
```

You only need to expose the root `FormGroup` from your component.

```js
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
  const formControls = {
    field: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  };

  formControls.field.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
    const value = formControls.field.value;
    // TODO: perform action based on value
  });

  this.form = this.formBuilder.group(formControls);  
}
```